# In which generality we have $K$-flat resolutions?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Let $\mathsf{A}$ be an abelian monoidal symmetric category (i.e., an abelian tensor category in the sense of Milne / Deligne). I wonder what more I should impose on $\mathsf{A}$ in order to have $K$-flat resolutions. (For example, it has long been known that Grothendieck abelian categories have enough $K$-injectives. Does imposing $\mathsf{A}$ to be Grothendieck suffices in our case?)

Supposing this to be the case, I would also like to know which properties of $\mathsf{A}$ do $\mathsf{D}(\mathsf{A})$ inherits. For example, is $\mathsf{D}(\mathsf{A})$ also symmetric monoidal with respect to the derived tensor product? Is it rigid whenever $\mathsf{A}$ is?

Comment: For the questions about rigidity, you need to consider the bounded derived category. For instance, if A is the category of finite dimensional k-vector spaces, then the dualizable objects in the derived category of A will be the perfect complexes of k-modules, hence those objects of D(A) with finitely many non-trivial cohomology groups.

Comment: For an abstract tensor structure on an abelian category (possibly Grothendieck), there could be strange phenomena: it could be that left deriving the tensor functor as a functor in two variables and evaluating at objects X and Y does not give you the same thing than evaluating at Y the left derived functor X$\otimes(-)$, even if both could be well defined.

Comment: Oh... that's very interesting. Do you know some reference for your second comment?

Comment: Perhaps we can impose a natural condition to avoid this problem?

Comment: I think natural family of examples come if you start from a small tensor additive category C and consider A={additive presheaves on C}, with the tensor structure produced by Day convolution. You have enough projective and they are good enough to derive the tensor product, but they are not flat in the usual sense in general.

Comment: To avoid problems, you have to ask for enough flat objects: objects $X$ such that $X\otimes(-)$ is exact. What I meant in my previous comments is that you may have a Grothendieck abelian category with enough projectives, but it could be that they are not flat in this sense, although they allow to produce left derived functors of any additive functors.

Comment: Oh I understand it now! Sure! Do you know if a Grothendieck abelian monoidal symmetric category has enough (K-)flats? Or anything more general than what's in Spaltenstein's paper?

Comment: No, that is my point. In the case of additive presheaves on C as above with a tensor structure on C extended by Day convolution, I do not know if tensoring by a representable presheaf is an exact functor. In fact it is unlikely to be true in general. This gives an example of a Grothendieck abelian category with enough projectives which do not look like flat objects.

Comment: A sufficient condition for $K$-flat resolutions to exist in a symmetric monoidal Grothendieck abelian category is simply that there is a generating family of flat objects: this follows from a combination of Remark 2.12, Prop. 3.7, and Cor. 3.5 in this paper: https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/hha/content/vols/0011/0001/a011/index.php